# Google anayltics number of conversions does not match with number of

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

We got the problem that we configurated in our Google analytics account the goal tracking and e-commerce conversion tracking (for the same page). But there's always the problem that the number of goals is correct (for example 20) but number of ecommerce transacions is only lower (for example 11). I think that the 2 number should match identically, or is this not possibile according to the analytics-system?

Comment: Goals and conversions are not necessarily related. However usually you should have more conversions than goals (since a goal is counted only once per session). So there is something wrong either with your transaction tracking or with your goal setup (the latter would probably off topic on stackoverflow since goals are not set within the code). I assume the close vote is because there is not enough info to narrow your problem down, since the literal answer to your question (it's technically possible but would be rather unusual) would be in no way helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the first response Eike! Now we've found the error. We've done the following changes:

Load ga('require', 'ecommerce'); instead of ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');

+

Load the ecommerce tracking (ga('require', 'ecommerce'); ...) right after ga('send', 'pageview'); - Normally there were some other analytics data between

+

Analytics lowercase filter

+

Analytics target tracking use "starts with" instead of "exact" target page path